# Cannot resolver symbole validate resource reference inside android xml

Tags: android, xml

So every thing works fine and after generating an apk, when I try to run it in emulator it gives me an error

> Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error
>   while Launching activity

Here is my configuration:
[image: Here is my configuration]

When I go into detail I see this error.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/meme_creator_icon8"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="cs4295.memecreator.WelcomeScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> android:name="cs4295.memecreator.**WelcomeScreenActivity**"

WelcomeScreenActivity comes in red colour.

Here is my WelcomeScreenActivity code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="cs4295.memecreator.WelcomeScreenAcivity" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: Try `Invalidate Caches` and `Restart` From File menu.

Comment: Do you have a Java class called **WelcomeScreenActivity**?